# Decimal Configuration, Incomplete Data Fetch From DataBase

Tags: database, windows, vb.net, plsql, publish

I have a select that calls data from the database. I want to transfer the publication of Windows Server 2008 to 2019 in some methods has input string was not in a correct format error
because .Parameters.Item("RET_VAL").Value.ToString in 2008 server return 0.7 value in 2019 server return .7 value

```
 Dim result As Double
    Dim oCmm As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand("GetPhaDrugFranshiz")
    oCmm.Parameters.Add(cls_General.Create_Ora_Param("RET_VAL", ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, OracleDbType.Double))
    oCmm.Parameters.Add(cls_General.Create_Ora_Param("v_patientid", ParameterDirection.Input, OracleDbType.Decimal, v_patientid.Length, v_patientid))
    oCmm.Parameters.Add(cls_General.Create_Ora_Param("v_usercat", ParameterDirection.Input, OracleDbType.Char, v_usercat.Length, v_usercat))
    oCmm.Parameters.Add(cls_General.Create_Ora_Param("v_cust_no", ParameterDirection.Input, OracleDbType.Char, v_cust_no.Length, v_cust_no))
    oCmm.Parameters.Add(cls_General.Create_Ora_Param("v_dblinks_id", ParameterDirection.Input, OracleDbType.Decimal, v_dblinks_id.Length, v_dblinks_id))
    oCmm.Parameters.Add(cls_General.Create_Ora_Param("v_cust_service_type", ParameterDirection.Input, OracleDbType.Char, cust_service_type.Length, cust_service_type))
    oCmm.Parameters.Add(cls_General.Create_Ora_Param("v_drug_code", ParameterDirection.Input, OracleDbType.Char, 5, drugCode))
    With oCmm
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        .CommandTimeout = 90
        .Connection = pCnn
        .Transaction = Tran
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
            result = Double.Parse(.Parameters.Item("RET_VAL").Value.ToString)
    End With
    Return result
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3Liu.png)
Please help me to find out what might be causing this problem.

Comment: Move `oCmm.ExecuteNonQuery()` and `result =  ...` outside the `With` block. Evaluate the what `.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns (it could be `-1`).

Comment: Rather than trying to parse a string, have you tried to parse the parameter value? E.g. `result = Double.Parse(.Parameters.Item("RET_VAL").Value)`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting ret_val as double, so try to get it as string if the data transfers correctly from database. then you can parse it by

```
double dblresult = double.Parse(result);
```

if needed.